# Validate time overlap in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, date

I have a movie ticketing service that has movie, showtime, and screen models. For a certain screen I have to make sure that the showtimes do not overlap. What is the best approach for doing this?

My migrations are the following

Movies

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :movies do |t|
      t.string  :title
      t.text    :plot
      t.integer :length_minutes
      t.string  :poster
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Showtimes

```
class CreateShowtimes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :showtimes do |t|
      t.references :movie, index: true
      t.timestamp  :start_time, null: false
      t.timestamp  :end_time, null: false
      t.references :screen
    end
  end
end
```

and Screen

```
class CreateScreens < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :screens do |t|
      t.string :name, unique: true
      t.integer :seats_available, null: false, limit: 1
    end
  end
end
```

This is the create method in my ShowtimesController

```
def create
    movie_length = Movie.find(showtime_params[:movie_id]).length_minutes
    start_time = Time.new(showtime_params["start_time(1i)"], showtime_params["start_time(2i)"], showtime_params["start_time(3i)"], showtime_params["start_time(4i)"], showtime_params["start_time(5i)"])
    end_time = start_time + movie_length.minutes

    @showtime = Showtime.new(showtime_params)
    @showtime.start_time = start_time
    @showtime.end_time = end_time
    if @showtime.save
      redirect_to @showtime, notice: 'Showtime was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

How can I validate that two showtimes for the same screen dont overlap. Im using postgresql as my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 validate :no_overlap

 def no_overlap
   showtimes = Showtime.where(screen_id: screen_id)
   overlap = showtimes.select{ |showtime| (start_time - showtime.end_time) * (showtime.start_time - end_time) > 0  }
   unless overlap.blank?
     raise "Conflicting showings for screen: #{screen_id}"
   end
 end
```

Comment: Hi @toddmetheny, I get the following error 'ERROR:  null value in column "start_time" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (10, 1, null, null, 1).'

Comment: @jlarding Are you sure you're passing your times through your form? Try removing the validation and then in your controller do a puts params.inspect and make sure they are making it through to your controller action.

Comment: The end_time parameter is set in my controller because is calculated by using the length of the movie and the start time. How can I pass the end date to the params without it coming from the form

Comment: @jlarding before you call Showtime.new add the end_time to the showtime_params by saying showtime_params[:end_time] = end_time.

Comment: also--what are you trying to do w/ all those arguments you're passing to start_time?

Comment: Im trying to construct the date to save from each piece sent from the form. Is there a better way to do that? After doing this `showtime_params[:start_time] = start_time
    showtime_params[:end_time] = end_time` I get this `{"movie_id"=>"1", "start_time(1i)"=>"2016", "start_time(2i)"=>"3", "start_time(3i)"=>"7", "start_time(4i)"=>"20", "start_time(5i)"=>"00", "screen_id"=>"1"}`

Comment: check out the form helpers for time. time_select will potentially do what you're looking for: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_select

Comment: The time_select is only for time, and I need to get date and time for the start_time

Comment: select_datetime optionally includes all the way down to seconds: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_datetime

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the Showtime model:

```
validate :validate_no_overlap_on_screen

def validate_no_overlap_on_screen
  return if Showtime.where('screen_id = ? AND (end_time > ? OR start_time < ?)',
    screen_id, start_time, end_time).none?
  errors.add(:start_time, 'Times overlap another showtime on this screen')
end
```

Comment: Hi @MTarantini, I get the following error when implementing this solution ERROR:  null value in column "start_time" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, 1, null, null, 1).

Comment: I think this should be a better solution than the accepted answer. because it does the job on the database side. You really do not want to pull data in-memory at client side and do ruby slow comparison!

Comment: Hi @jlarding, that error has more to do with your migration than this solution: `t.timestamp  :start_time, null: false`. Your Showtime model should have validations to check that start_time and end_time are present.